# Changing Sprites using scripts in Unity2D C#

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I am wanting to make a birds-eye view pixel-art game.

I currently have two sprite sheets set up, and split and whatnot
groundSheet and characterSheet these are split up into

```
ground_0_0_0 (A concrete floor)

ground_1_0_0 (grass)

character_0_0_0 (man idle animation frame 1)

character_0_0_1 (man idle animation frame 2)

character_0_1_0 (man run animation frame 1)

character_0_1_1 (man run animation frame 2)

character_1_0_0 (woman idle animation frame 1)

character_1_0_1 (woman idle animation frame 2)

character_1_1_0 (woman run animation frame 1)

character_1_1_1 (woman run animation frame 2)
```

The numbers after are a note as to:

first number - the main set of sprite animations (eg man)

second number - the animation set in use (eg run or idle)

third number - the frame of said animation.
(the ground has this as i plan to have animated grounds late on)

Now, I wish to make a script for the character (and ground alike) that has an editable value that is view able in the unity editor, for example how things like the sprite renderer has sprite, colour etc. Which dictates what first number to use (see above) what second number and the delay for the animation of the third number. This will then tell the sprite renderer what pictures to load and how quickly to load them. I also wish for the script to scan for the file starting with for example character_0_0_ and then count how many files after it, so it knows what to do when animating. I would like this script to be checking for a change in one of the variables viewable in the unity editor to change and as soon as it does it checks everything it needs for an animtion.

Something else could be done where there is only 1 box to edit in unity, which you put character_0_0_ or ground_1_0_ or something similar, and it checks everything that way (it also makes the script universal, and usable on the ground, character and walls (which I am adding later)).

This may seem confusing, but it make sense for me and many of you will probably mention a much easier way to do animations and such, but please only say these if it does what I want above.

```
For scripts and such my file layout:
/Assets
/scripts
    ground.cs
    character.cs
/sprites
    characterSheet.png
        character_0_0_0
        character_0_0_1
        character_0_1_0
        character_0_1_1
        character_1_0_0
        character_1_0_1
        character_1_1_0
        character_1_1_1
    groundSheet.png
        ground_0_0_0
        ground_1_0_0
```

(For some reason Stack overflow said the above was code, so i had to make it as that)

ground.cs and character.cs are the scripts in which I want to made as explained above.
In my object view thingy I have
Main Camera
ground
character

I am practically a newb to C# and JS I know bascially the grammar of C# (like where to use {} and put ; at the end of the lines). If you help me with this, i request that you explain the script, like use the // thing to simply explain what each command does, I know a few but not all of them. And I know someone is going to say it is really well documented in tutorial X and such, but most tutorials are not in unity 5 and while helping with the matter do not touch on it exactly.

Thank you for your help, if there is anything about this question/request that you do not understand (It is pretty complex) I will explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am completely wrong, but it seems to me that you are trying to recreate an Animation system.

Is there a specific reason for which you wouldn't use Unity's animation system?

You can do everything that you describe here with it (change sprite, choose animation speed). And you would have almost no code to write. Just drag and drop you sprites in the editor for a start

---

**EDIT - answer to first comment:**

What you should do is create all the animations you need. Then in the animator, you choose which condition will trigger a transition to another animation (for instance, boolean jump is true will transition to animation jump). Then in your code you can call GetComponent().SetBool("Jump", true).

To have different character, you can create different gameObjects (one per character). They all have a different animator with animations specific to the character.
The other solutiojn if you really want one one gameObject and one animator is that you also add string condition to you animation (example, if character=="character1" and jump==true, transition to jump animation).

If I were you I would really focus on testing and learning all you can do with Unity animator. I can't think of a case were you would need to recreate the animation system yourself

Comment: The reason is since I want to be able to change the animation using a script, and with the current animation system I do not think that is possible, but if it is please let me know.

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope it makes it more clear. You can definitely have an animator switching between many animations. And you can communicate with it through code

Answer (score 0):

Your question was long winded and hard to understand but ill try to help, 
firstly if you want editable values in the unity editor I would Suggest using a serialized structure of information like this

```
[System.Serializable] // this makes it viewable in the inspector
public struct Sprite_Manager;
{  

    public Sprite[] Render_Sprites; // array of sprites to store sprites
    public SpriteRenderer S_Renderer;
    public float Anim_Delay;
}

public class Character : MonoBehavior {

  Sprite_Manager SMG = new Sprite_Manager(); // instantiate a new instance of the struct                                                                          

      void Set_Sprite()
       {
             for(int i = 0; i < SMG.Render_Sprites.Length; i++)
              {
                     SMG.S_Renderer.sprite = SMG.Render_Sprites[i];
              }


       }

      void Update
      {

         Invoke("Set_Sprite", SMG.Anim_Delay);

      }

}
```

Not sure if this is exactly what your looking for but this is one way you could setup a structure of sprite based information and use Invoke to setup some sort of delay when passing new sprites to the renderer.

Comment: I did realise the complicated-ness of my request/question, I assume I have to fill gaps in your code somewhere, if not I get errors. Meanwhile Ill attempt to stop the errors, if you know whether the unity animation editor can be changed using scripts, then please let me know.

Comment: I have managed to get the animation editor to work, my only problem now is how to use the conditions section, I will create a separate question for that though.

Comment: My answer was more or a less an example then the right answer, I was mostly trying to show how you can use structures to make information editable in the inspector, but yea you can create references to Animator Components And AnimationClips aswell